# Wie nennt man jemanden, der etwas (neutral) erwartet?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-word-request

Wie nennt man jemanden, der etwas erwartet, d.h. der es für wahrscheinlich hält, dass es passieren wird? Wenn er es freudig erwartet, könnte (!) man ihn einen Optimisten nennen, wenn er es mit Sorge erwartet einen Pessimisten, wobei ich den von @tohuwawohu geäußerten Einwand gelten lasse. Wenn er es nicht erwartet, würde vielleicht "Skeptiker" passen: "Ich bin skeptisch, dass es passieren wird."

Doch wie nennt man den "etwas neutral Erwartenden"?

Beispiel: "Manche erwarten, dass Künstliche Allgemeine Intelligenz schon in den nächsten Jahren auftauchen wird, andere sind da skeptisch." Wie referiere ich auf die Erstgenannten, wenn ich mich auf die Zweitgenannten einfach als auf "die Skeptiker" beziehen kann?
"Die Skeptiker werden vielleicht recht behalten" ist ein im Kontext akzeptabler Satz, der mein Sprachgefühl nicht verletzt. "Die Erwartenden werden vielleicht recht behalten" würde ich niemals sagen oder schreiben wollen.

Comment: M.E. ist Optimismus nicht gleich "freudige" Erwartung, vice versa für Pessimismus. Beides betrifft m.E. die Einschätzung der *Wahrscheinlichkeit*, nicht der "Erwünschtheit" des Ereignisses (bzw. die Wahrscheinlichkeit eines positiven oder alternativ negativen Ergebnisses). Optimist wie Pessimist würden einen Lottogewinn ähnlich freudig "erwarten", jedoch seine Wahrscheinlichkeit unterschiedlich beurteilen. Ich sehe da keine Position dazwischen. M.E. bedarf die Frage einer Präzisierung.

Comment: Du meinst wie in "Hans-Peter erwartet ein paar Antworten auf seine Frage"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wenn man nicht ausdrücken will, wie jemand eine mögliche Zukunft sieht, aber sagen will, **dass** die Person genau diese Zukuft erwartet, also voraussagt, dass sie eintrifft, passt vielleicht "Prophet", "Augur", oder ["Prognostiker".](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Prognostiker) Wobei letzteres eigentlich eher bedeutet, dass sich die Person mit Voraussagen über das Thema beschäftigt.

> Untergangsprophet
> Klimawandelaugur
> Rezessionsprognostiker

Comment: "Prognostiker" trifft es bisher am Besten. Danke. (Jemand, der etwas erwartet, *hat* sich ja offenbar mit dem Thema und der Zukunft beschäftigt;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ein häufig mit Optimist und Pessimist verwendeter Begriff ist der Realist. Vielleicht passt das in deinem Kontext.

Ansonsten einfach: der/die Erwartende?

Comment: Danke, aber das ist nicht neutral genug. Realist klingt, als stimme man ihm zu in seiner Einschätzung. Aber auch in dieser Hinsicht möchte ich neutral bleiben.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: Ich sehe das nicht so: Wenn jemand eine "realistische" Einschätzung einer Sache hat, muss ich ihm nicht unbedingt zustimmen... es kann mehrere verschiedene, gleichbedeutende realistische Einschätzungen geben....

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker ich habe noch die offensichtlichste Lösung hinzugefügt. Kannst du ansonsten noch mindestens einen Beispielsatz anfügen wo das Wort auftauchen soll?

Comment: @Tode: Aber warum sollte der Erwartende realistischer als der Skeptiker sein?

Comment: @infinitezero: Ich habe ein Beispiel in meiner Frage gegeben. "Der Erwartende" klingt wirklich nicht nach schönem Deutsch.